# Using ListTile and getting exception: RenderBox was not laid out

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to use `ListTile()` inside Column and Rows but it is throwing an exception:

```
Exception caught by rendering library 
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
```

This is the code:

```
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card()
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                    child: ListTile(),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
```

How can we solve this?

Comment: can you share your whole dart file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Expanded** widget

```
       Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card()
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Card(
                      child: ListTile(),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```